# Country switcher, then option to choose language for that country

Tags: multi-language, plugin-wpml

The client will have about 30 different country version…and each country has at least english language (and 6 countries have additional second language, like austria, germany- german, japan (japanese), etc.)- so I assume we have one country switcher allowing to switch between versions (where countries and languages are only versions)…does that make sense?

In the beginning I was thinking of multisite, wehere each country is one site and each site can have up to two languages (english and local if available)…and URL structure would be like /at/en (/country/language)then decided to go with single site because its easier to maintain and setup.

So basically…one switcher for country and one switcher for en/local language would be best if possible somehow
but don’t´know yet how to solve that exactly.
products will be mostly the same between countries- so we change the backend functionality of wpml with hooks to use the „same“ woo commerce product (instead of duplicating each product for 30+ versions)

It´s not possible with wpml out of the box- but addressing the hooks it can be customized

Any sugesstion?

Comment: If you just want to change only language according to country then this article is for you http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-easily-create-a-multilingual-wordpress-site/